# DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist error message. Selenium in Python running on MacOS

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've got a project that uses the Chrome webdriver with Selenium and came across an intermittent DevToolsActivePort issue that prevented the webdriver from starting. As usual, it was a simple problem, but it took a while to determine the cause.

TLDR: Try manually opening and closing Chrome. Check your script's shutdown process.

Software Versions:

- macOS: 13.0.1
- Python: 3.9.6
- Selenium: 4.8.2
- Chrome: 113.0.5672.92

##### Error message:

```
Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Here is a snippet of the driver initialization:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

prefs = {
  "download.default_directory": Download_dir,
  'download.prompt_for_download': False,
  'directory_upgrade': True,
  'safebrowsing.enabled': True,
  'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1,
  'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 0,
}

options.add_argument("--headless=new")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/")
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 3') # Profile Folder Name
options.binary_location = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

I saw a lot of posts suggesting to add some options to the driver such as `--no-sandbox`, `--disable-dev-shm-usage` which both remove security layers, not ideal, and also did not resolve the issue in my case. I also saw a suggestion to add the `--remote-debugging-port=<example port>` option to manually choose the port. This is probably the cause of the issue, but I could not find the correct port to use.

I ended up solving the issue by simply opening and quitting Chrome before starting the script. I believe the error was caused by the script not properly closing the Chrome instance which may have caused the debugging port mismatch. By opening and closing Chrome manually, I could ensure a proper shutdown, and the selenium fired right up.

I have now added `driver.close()` / `driver.quit()` to the keyboard interrupt block and it seems to have resolved the issue.

Hope this helps the other noobs out there.

##### Tried:

Initializing the Chrome webdriver in Selenium.

##### Expected:

Selenium initializes Chrome webdriver.

##### Results:

Occasionally would fail `unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist` error.

##### Solution:

1. Stop the script.
2. Open Chrome.
3. Close Chrome.
4. Start the script.
5. Fix the shutdown procedure.
6. Profit?

Answer (score 1):

If you run your tests on a server, it might help to set the DISPLAY variable to something (any nonempty value?). Even if Chrome runs in `--headless` mode.

I got these crashes while connecting to a Linux server (which I wanted to run my PHP/Codeception tests on) with `ssh <servername>` and then both Chrome and Chromium failed to start (to run tests in headless mode), resulting in
`unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist`.

Connecting with `ssh -Y <servername>` helped to get rid of the errors. My `$DISPLAY` variable on my ssh terminal was set to e.g. `localhost:11.1` and that was sufficient.
A nonexisting DISPLAY variable led to errors.

(I haven't investigated this further).
(I just realized you run tests on a Mac, so my advice might not apply, but perhaps it helps someone else)

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer! `ssh -Y ...` solved the problem on my Raspeberry Pi 2 too!

Answer (score 0):

In your code just change this

```
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

To

```
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

I have also verified same and Tested with version 4.8.2 worked fine

Comment: Hey Abhay, I had tried that as well, but the issue remained. 

In my case the issue was caused by an improper shut down procedure. Temporary fix was just opening and closing chrome, but the solution was to make sure the chrome instances were closed when the script stopped or got interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

In my recent experience using Selenium + Chrome Driver, I think it is necessary to share a series of things that can solve this error, because this could be due to many things in the configuration you use, but here are some things that have worked for me on several occasions with this problem:

1. Don't miss the `.stop()` and `.start()` methods for `Service` instance

   `serv = Service("/Users/nemo/boto/chrome_driver__114.0.5735.90/chromedriver")`
   `serv.start()` (and .stop(), of course)
2. The same thing with the service you need to do with Driver (`driver.close()` and `driver.quit()`, in that order)
3. The two previous things can be considered in the keyboard interrupt, here a short example to how to do that in `Python`:

   ```
   import keyboard

   def wait_interrupt():
       keyboard.wait('ctrl+c')
       print('Oh, there is a signal')
       # Here code what you need to do...
       # call wait_interrupt again to continue
       wait_interrupt()

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       wait_interrupt()
   ```
4. Update your driver version
5. Close and reopen Chrome
6. Reset your Chrome settings (this will not affect your passwords or favorites) using `chrome://settings/reset`
7. Try to disable experimental features in Chrome options arguments like `--headless=new`

Answer (score 0):

Adding below argument fixed my issue.

```
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-pipe')
```

Comment: this didn't help, but changed the error for me :)